# Add two dataframes without sorting index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add the values in 2 dataframes, by index value (0 for missing), without sorting the index.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],['Yes','Maybe','No'],['Num'])
df2=pd.DataFrame([4,5],['Yes','No'],['Num'])
df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
       Num
Maybe  2.0
No     8.0
Yes    5.0
```

I'd like to get:

```
Yes    5.0
Maybe  2.0
No     8.0
```

Concat adds extra rows instead of adding the values, and setting the index of one equal to the other before adding causes the values to be mislabeled.  I'd like this to work for any index and be able to count on the same order.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to index search when adding together, so we can fix `reindex`

```
out = df1.add(df2,fill_value=0).reindex(df1.index)
Out[281]: 
       Num
Yes    5.0
Maybe  2.0
No     8.0
```